# Allowing a nested attribute for a User with Devise in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, strong-parameters

I'm upgrading from Rails 3.2 to 4.0 and am using Devise for my `User` model. Previously I had `attr_accessible` attributes in my `User` model:

```
attr_accessible :username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
```

Now according to the [Devise documentation for strong parameters](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters), I have to do the following in my `application_controller.rb` in a `before_filter` method:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :current_password) }
```

That seems fine, but I also have an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in my `User` model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :staff, reject_if: :new_record?
```

How do I specify that in my `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update)`? This is not clear to me.

***UPDATE***: I tried the following:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :current_password, staff_attributes: [:notification_email]) }
```

In particular, I added `staff_attributes: [:notification_email]` as a parameter to the `permit` method. 3 major problems happened when I simply saved a user edit form without making any changes:

1. Error displayed: "Staff notification email has already been taken" (I have `validates :notification_email, uniqueness: true, allow_nil: true` in the `Staff` model)
2. Error displayed: "Staff project can't be blank" (I have `validates_presence_of :project_id` in the `Staff` model)
3. Even though I received those 2 errors, the `staff` model associated with the `user` was wiped out, all attributes were set to `nil` except the `notification_email`. This included the `user_id` field, so the `staff` object was no longer connected to the `user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are nested attributes, so you need to add them in following way:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
  u.permit(:username, :staff_attributes => [:name, :position, :etc]) 
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was surprising. I added this: `, staff_attributes: [:notification_email]` to the `permit` call. Because I only want users to be able to update their `notification_email` if they're a staff member. What ended up happening is all other fields, including the `user_id` field of `Staff` were set to `nil`! So the user is no longer a staff member! Is there a way to only be able to update 1 of the staff attributes? Or at least not set all other fields to `nil`? Also, when I edited the user I got an error that another field of `staff` was required, even though it still `nil`ed all fields.

Comment: The problem was I didn't have `:id` as one of the elements in the array pointed to by `staff_attributes`. Now everything works perfect!